# How to correct error when aggregating from subquery

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT store_id,
(CASE WHEN txns_A>0 AND txns_B=0 THEN 'A Only' WHEN txns_A=0 AND txns_B>0 THEN 'B Only' END) A_B_indicator,
sum(1) cnt_customers,
sum(spend_A+spend_B)/sum(txns_A+txns_B) avg_receipt
FROM(
    SELECT store_id, cust_id
    SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='A' THEN spend else 0 end) spend_A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='B' THEN spend else 0 end) spend_B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='A' THEN spend else 0 end) txns_A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='B' THEN spend else 0 end) txns_B
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY store_id, cust_id
    ) table2;
```

However, this generates an error because store_id is not in a `GROUP BY` clause. When I rewrite the query to include a `GROUP BY store_id` clause, it complains that the aggregate columns are not in the `Group By`. However, if I add them by rewriting the `Group By` to be `Group BY 1,2,3,4`, this also generates an error (`Not yet supported place for UDAF Sum`).

How can I rewrite this query to be error-free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT store_id,
        (CASE WHEN SUM(txns_A) > 0 AND SUM(txns_B) = 0 THEN 'A Only'
              WHEN SUM(txns_A) = 0 AND SUM(txns_B) > 0 THEN 'B Only'
         END) as A_B_indicator,
       COUNT(*) as cnt_customers,
       SUM(spend_A+spend_B)/sum(txns_A+txns_B) as avg_receipt
FROM (SELECT store_id, cust_id
             SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='A' THEN spend else 0 end) as spend_A,
             SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='B' THEN spend else 0 end) as spend_B,
             SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='A' THEN spend else 0 end) as txns_A,
             SUM(CASE WHEN A_B_indicator='B' THEN spend else 0 end) as txns_B
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY store_id, cust_id
    ) table2
GROUP BY store_id;
```

Comment: thank you. Just so I understand, your approach is to use aggregate functions in the case statement in order to avoid including those lines in the Group By? And that's because SQL does not require aggregate functions such as SUM, COUNT, etc. to be included in Group By?

Comment: @Caerus . . . The purpose is to implement the logic that you want, which is presumably that "A Only" means "A Only" *over all the rows for each `store_id`.